# standard deviation of specific row numbers and put the value in another row & column in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have following data:

```
Date                 Value          Std.Dev
11/30/2015 10:00     0  
11/30/2015 10:30    -0.002400962    
11/30/2015 11:00    -0.004819286    
11/30/2015 11:30    -0.000805477    
11/30/2015 12:00    -0.001612904    
11/30/2015 12:30    -0.003233633    
11/30/2015 13:00     0.000809389    
11/30/2015 13:30     0.005647453    
11/30/2015 14:00    -0.002416433    
11/30/2015 14:30    -0.006472515    
11/30/2015 15:00    -0.002438035    
11/30/2015 15:30     0  
11/30/2015 16:30    -0.000814001    
12/1/2015 9:00       0.006493529    0.002931114
12/1/2015 9:30      -0.001619434    0.003657839
12/1/2015 10:00     -0.003246756    0.00363798
12/1/2015 10:30     -0.002442004    0.003519869
12/1/2015 11:00      0.000814664    0.003551266
12/1/2015 11:30     -0.001629992    0.00357286
12/1/2015 12:00      0.000815328    0.003504601
12/1/2015 12:30     -1.11022E-16    0.003504796
12/1/2015 13:00     -0.000815328    0.002981979
```

Std.Dev should start calculation from `row number 14`. Because I am calculating first std.dev on previous days values. And `standard deviation for row 14` will be calculated on `row=1` of Value to `row=13` of Value. And thus it should go on. So `Std.Dev_at_row_number_15 = STDEV(Value2:Value14)`.
`Std.Dev_at_row_number_16 = STDEV(Value3:Value15)`. And so on....

Can you please suggest any function for this kind of calculation in R. In excel it is very easy. But if you can suggest similar in R, it will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Pardon me for bad English if any. Please let me know in comments if you want more details or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not the most efficient way, but maybe sufficient for you (with x denoting your data frame):

```
    for(counter in 14:nrow(x)){
       x[counter,3] <- sd(x[(counter-13):(counter-1),2])
    }
```

But again, that's definitely not the most efficient way.

Comment: will that be sd instead of std??

Comment: Yes, sry was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

For a data.frame, df, you can get this as follows with `sapply`:

```
df$st.dev <- c(rep(NA, 13), sapply(13:(nrow(df)-1), function(i) sd(df$Value[(i-12):i])))
```

`sapply` will run through the selected rows and the function that follows will repeatedly calculate the standard deviations for the selected rows. I prepend NAs to this output so that it can be added to the data.frame.

**data**

I cheated a little in reading in the data, but it doesn't affect the result.

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="Date   Time      Value         
11/30/2015 10:00     0  
11/30/2015 10:30    -0.002400962    
11/30/2015 11:00    -0.004819286    
11/30/2015 11:30    -0.000805477    
11/30/2015 12:00    -0.001612904    
11/30/2015 12:30    -0.003233633    
11/30/2015 13:00     0.000809389    
11/30/2015 13:30     0.005647453    
11/30/2015 14:00    -0.002416433    
11/30/2015 14:30    -0.006472515    
11/30/2015 15:00    -0.002438035    
11/30/2015 15:30     0  
11/30/2015 16:30    -0.000814001    
12/1/2015 9:00       0.006493529   
12/1/2015 9:30      -0.001619434   
12/1/2015 10:00     -0.003246756   
12/1/2015 10:30     -0.002442004   
12/1/2015 11:00      0.000814664   
12/1/2015 11:30     -0.001629992   
12/1/2015 12:00      0.000815328   
12/1/2015 12:30     -1.11022E-16   
12/1/2015 13:00     -0.000815328", as.is=TRUE, row)
```

Comment: It is giving error for my original data: replacement has 23 rows, data has 22.